# Properly chaining reducers when using combining them may not be appropriate

Tags: flux, redux, immutable.js

In my application, the state tree has this shape:

```
{
    ...otherReducers,
    rooms: Map({
        // room being the room's id
        room: Map({
             id: '',
             name: '',
             users: Map({
                 // user being the user's id
                 user: Map({
                     id: '',
                     name: '',
                     rank: ' '
                 })
             })
        })
    })
}
```

In order to update a user's state, I've been writing my reducers as follows:

```
function roomsReducer(state = Map(), action) {
    case USER_RENAME:
        return selectRoom(state, action);
    default:
        return state;
}

function selectRoom(state, action) {
    let room = state.get(action.payload.id);
    return state.set(action.payload.id, roomReducer(room, action));
}

// and so on and so forth until I reach the user I want to update
```

Is there a way I an combine the `users` reducer with `room`, despite it having `id` and `name` properties? If not, is there a better way I could be managing my state to make reducing more manageable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with how you structure your state. Editing users would be much easier if it was normalized like so:

```
{
  ...otherReducers,
  rooms: Map({
    5: Map({
      id: '5',
      name: 'some name',
      users: [1,4,52]
    })
  }),
  users: Map({
    1: Map({
      id: '1',
      name: 'Charles',
      range: 'Master'
    }),
    4: Map({
      id: '4',
      name: 'Sally',
      range: 'Master'
    }),
    52: Map({
      id: '52',
      name: 'Harry',
      range: 'Novice'
    })
  })
}
```